# Existe una forma para que Jackson ignore un objecto vacío al deserializar?

Tags: java, json, spring

Al momento de deserializar, es decir, al recibir un contenido de tipo JSON en un Controller y convertirlo en un objeto Java, ¿como puedo hacer para que Jackson ignore un objeto vacío?.

Estoy usando Jackson 2.6.6 y Spring 4.2.6

El contenido JSON que recibe mi controller es del siguiente modo:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "descripcion": "Descripción",
    "objetoContenido": {}
}
```

El problema es que el objeto "objetoContenido" se interpreta como tal y se instancia. Por lo tanto, luego de que mi controller recibe este JSON, me crea una instancia de ObjetoContenido y no necesito que se instancie sino que se interprete como **null**.

La solución más fácil sería que en el JSon ya esté con valor **null** de la siguiente forma:

```
 {
        "id": 2,
        "descripcion": "Descripción",
        "objetoContenido": null
    }
```

Pero no me es posible esta solución dado que el contenido JSON no depende de mí, sino que me llega de esa forma.

¿Existe una anotación al estilo @JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY) como explican [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089651/jackson-serialization-ignore-empty-values-or-null), pero que funcione para la deserialización que me sea útil en esta situación?

------------------------Información añadida-------------------------------------

Dejo una representación de mis clases a modo informativo:

Mi entidad en cuestión es de la siguiente manera:

```
public class Entidad {
    private long id;
    private String descripcion;
    private ObjetoContenido objetoContenido;

//Contructor, getters y setters omitidos

}
```

Y la clase del objeto que contiene mi entidad, que es de tipo ObjetoContenido, es de la siguiente manera:

```
public class ObjetoContenido {
    private long objContId;
    private String cadena;

//Contructor, getters y setters omitidos

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por desgracia, si viene como `"objetoContenido": {}` es un objeto instanciado de todas todas.

Como solución provisional, se me ocurre que en método get de la propiedad objetoContenido del objeto Entidad, preguntes por algún campo y si no tiene valor devuelvas null. Por ejemplo:

```
public ObjetoContenido getObjetoContenido {
    return objetoContenido.getObjContId() == 0 ? null : this.objetoContenido;
}
```

Otra opción sería que tu objeto "ObjectoContenido" tuviese una propiedad que indicase si está inicializado o no. Aplicándolo a la solución que te he propuesto quedaría algo así:

```
public class Entidad {
    private long id;
    private String descripcion;
    private ObjetoContenido objetoContenido;

//Contructor, getters y setters omitidos
    public ObjetoContenido getObjetoContenido {
        return objetoContenido.getInicializado() ? this.objetoContenido : null;
    }

    public setObjetoContenido(ObjetoContenido obj) {
        this.objetoContenido = obj;
        this.objetoContenido.setInicializado(true);
    }

}

public class ObjetoContenido {
    private bool inicializado = false;
    private long objContId;
    private String cadena;

//Contructor, getters y setters omitidos

}
```

No es que sea mucho mejor, pero por lo menos no tienes que depender de una propiedad que no controlas.

Espero que esto te sirva.

Answer (score 1):

Jackson tiene una propiedad que se coloca justo arriba de tu clase que usas como model. Por ejemplo:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MiModelo {
    ...
}
```

Ten en cuenta que esto debe de ir hasta arriba de tu clase y no para métodos individuales.

Puedes consultar las propiedades que provee [Jackson](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html) para que sepas lo que estas haciendo

Comment: Creo que Mau no necesita que se ignore la propiedad, sino que se creé el json con nulo en lugar de `{}`

Comment: @jasilva Exacto, de hecho ésta anotación no funciona en mi caso dado que no es una propiedad desconocida (es conocida pero está vacía), por lo tanto no la ignora. El resultado final de agregar @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) no afecta en nada en este caso en particular

Answer (score 1):

Con añadir justo encima de la clase la anotación y despues en el constructor inicializar el objeto que hereda de la clase a null lo tendrás solucionado

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)
public class Entidad {

  private long id;
  private String descripcion;

  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
  private ObjetoContenido objetoContenido;

  public Entidad() {
     this.objetoContenido = null;
  }
  ...........Getters and Setters................
}
```

Solucionarás el problema, y te aparecerá el parámetro como null en la respuesta json.

Si por el contrario no quieres que aparezca quitale la anotación @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)

Answer (score 0):

Si es para filtrar el contenido del objeto contenido en "objetoContenido" los parámetros de ese objeto serán null (si está por defecto). Se instanciará pero tendrá los valores por defecto.

En caso de que sea un array su longitud será cero.

Espero sirva, pues según entiendo Jackson no evita instanciarlo ya que precisamente el constructor lo crea vacío (valores por defecto) y establece los valores detectados en el JSON si los hay.

Comment: En realidad lo que necesito es que el objeto no se instancie y que al finalizar la deserialización, mi objeto "Entidad" tenga sus campos id y descripcion con sus respectivos valores y que el valor para el campo de tipo "ObjetoContenido" sea null. Hasta el momento no encontré una forma de indicarle a Jackson que al leer el JSON y encontrarse con "objetoContenido": {} dicho objeto no se instancie para que el valor del campo de tipo "ObjetoContenido" sea null